# How I find a suitable increment value

Tags: real-analysis

If I have three variables $x,y$ and $z$, where $x\lt z$ and $y\lt z$, then I need to make each value of $x$ and $y$ equal to or approximately equal to $z$ by adding a ratio of another variable, for example $a$.

To simplify my question:

Let $z=5,x=4,y=3,a=2$.
I need to make $z=y=x=5$ or very close to value the of $z$
by taking a ratio from $a$ and adding this ratio to the value of $x$ and $y$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are splitting $A$ into two pieces, adding one piece to $x$ and the other to $y$, and want the two sums close to $z$.  Do you have to use all of $A$?  If we specify that the two sums to be equal, we can choose a number $r$, add $rA$ to $x$ and $(1-r)A$ to $y$.  We are solving $x+rA=y+(1-r)A,\  2rA=y-x+a,\  r=\frac {y-x+A}{2A}$  Both sums will be $\frac {x+y+A}2$.  Whether this is at all close to $z$ depends on $z$.  Note that we have not used the value of $z$ in the calculation at all.

It could well be that this is not at all what you are asking.  Maybe it will help you write the question more clearly.